# How to highlight the selected tab in sap.m.IconTabBar?

Tags: sapui5

Dear SAPUI5 developers,

I have a `sap.m.IconTabBar` and I set the active tab by the code when the user switch between pages. I used the following code:

```
  sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("iconTabBar")).setSelectedKey("1");
```

The problem is that it switch the selected tab correctly to the first tab. But it does not show the blue line under the tab that shows it is selected.

Please look at the following images:

What shows when I select the first tab by code:

[image]

But what it shows when I press the tab by the mouse it shows a blue line under the icon like the following:

[image]

Comment: @Mehdi: this.createId()  will create a new ID for your iconTabBar. Can you please paste your view and controller code ?

Comment: I think u only need to fire the selection event (not tried though) after setting the selection [sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("iconTabBar")).fireSelect();]

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj The only part of my code that is related to selecting the tab is that line of the code. Your comment is correct but not relevant to my question.

Comment: @Ash Thanks for the answer but I don't why it does not work properly all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ash said in the comments you need to call `fireSelect` but this works just if user the second tab at first. If the user is on the first tab and switches between the pages then `fireSelect` does not act properly. Thus you need to select the second tab at first then it will works almost all times.

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("iconTabBar")).setSelectedKey("2");
sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("iconTabBar")).setSelectedKey("1");
sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("iconTabBar")).fireSelect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I had a look into the IconTabBar source Code and theres something I dont really get why but here is how it proceeds :

when you call IconTabBar.setSelectedKey(key), it calls IconTabHeader.setSelectedKey(key)

then internally the IconTabBarHeader calls setSelectedItem(item, true)

the 'true' here is important, the parameter is named 'bAPIchange' in the setSelectedItem function, and it is used as condition for the fireSelect() :

```
if (!bAPIchange) {
    // fire event on iconTabBar
    if (bIsParentIconTabBar) {
        oParent.fireSelect({
            selectedItem: this.oSelectedItem,
            selectedKey: sSelectedKey,
            item: this.oSelectedItem,
            key: sSelectedKey
        });
    } else {
        // fire event on header
        this.fireSelect({
            selectedItem: this.oSelectedItem,
            selectedKey: sSelectedKey,
            item: this.oSelectedItem,
            key: sSelectedKey
        });
    }
}
```

Which explains why the event is not fired in your case

Comment: Dear @Ash, yes it is good. But it just fires the `Select` function. It works when the user selected the second tab first and then try to switch between items. In this case when the first tab is selected and user switches between items then it does not color the icon. Thus I think the answer of Majid is more efficient. But your answer is also good to know.